# Intuition of a norm vector space/ infinite dimensional vector space

Tags: normed-spaces, inner-products

I'm finding it terribly difficult to build an intuition of what a norm vector space and an infinite dimensional vector space is. There aren't any good notes online that builds  the intuition-most notes are overwhelmingly detailed which doesn't quite serve any purpose for me at this point.

Would someone be helpful enough to give me an intuitive description of what those concepts are? Even better if someone could connect the above to orthonormal basis.

Comment: At this point, you might have to build more "algebraic" intuition. At first, it helps to think of an infinite dimensional vector space as a finite dimensional space with some exceptions. The number of exceptions you need to keep in mind depends on the "additional structures" your vector space has. For example, if it is an inner product space, then you can still keep orthogonality.
One property that is quite commonly mentioned is that a closed and bounded set is not necessarily compact in an infinite dimensional Hilbert space.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think an *easy* example of an infinite dimensional vector space would be to consider a **sequence space**. Concretely consider the space $\mathcal{l}^2(\mathbb{R})$, which consists of all infinite sequences

$$ \mathbf{x}=(x_1, x_2, \ldots )$$

with elements $x_i \in \mathbb{R}$.

You could view this as vectors, just that you have infinitely many coordinates.

Endow this space with a norm that is derived from the usual Pythagorean theorem:

$$\|\mathbf{x}\|^2 := \sum_i x_i^2.$$

Then this gives you an infinite dimensional vector space with which you can work with almost in the same way as with the usual finite dimensional spaces.

In fact it also has an inner product given by

$$<\mathbf{x},\mathbf{y}> := \sum_i x_i y_i$$

and has an orthonormal basis with respect to this inner product.

Comment: So what I did was to read up on the P-Norm. For p =1, the Norm is a representation of 'steps' which occurs recursively up till a point-commonly called "Taxicab geometry.
For P=2, the Norm is a Euclidean length. Geometrically, P=1 is at least equal to or greater than P=2 and P=2 is at least equals to or greater than P=3. By induction, 
$$P=\infty$$ is the smallest. But how does one even 'visualise' this?

Answer (score 1):

One standard example the vector space of all real valued continuos functions defined on $[0,1]$, let's call it $V$.  Convince yourself that $V$ indeed is a vector space if you define the sum $f+g$ for $f$ and $g$ in $V$ to be the function $x\mapsto f(x)+g(x)$ and $cf$ is defined by $x\mapsto cx$ for any real $c$.

One may define an inner product of $V$ by
$$\langle f,g\rangle:=\int_0^1f(x)g(x)\,dx.$$
Verify that $\langle.,.\rangle$ is indeed an inner product.  Then, e.g., all straight lines with zero $2/3$ are orthogonal to the identity function.

Define as usual $\|f\|:=\sqrt{\langle f,f\rangle}$.  Then $B^{\|.\|}(0,1)$,the ball with radius $1$ centered at $0$ generated by $\|.\|$, is the set of all functions satisfying $\|f\|^2=\int_0^1 f^2(x)\,dx\leq1$.

But you may equip $V$ with a different norm $\|.\|_1$ defined by
$$\|f\|_1:=\max_{[0,1]}f(x).$$
Imagine what the ball $B^{\|.\|_1}(0,1)$ is now.  Furthermore, convince yourself that the set $B^{\|.\|}(0,1)$ is unbounded in respect to $\|.\|_1$.

Comment: it might be nice not denoting the sup norm by $\|\cdot\|_1$ :)

Comment: @user251257 I' ve just enumerate the norms ...